# How do I call a function of an already deployed contract several times in one transaction?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

Assuming I have:

```
Contract A:
function X(address) {};

Contract B:
function multipleExecuter(){}
```

Where Contract A is not mine and is an already deployed contract i.e. I have the address and source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either copy and paste the function executing code multiple times into a new function. Then just call that function.

OR

You can run a loop and execute the function over a certain index.

Both these are not really great coding practice, but it will do. (Also remember to import the other contract into the new one)